# Skype not responding to Ubuntu

Tags: skype, webcam, acer

I'm having problems downloading Skye to Ubuntu that my sister's husband installed on my Acer Aspire One computer. The Acer once had Windows 7 on it with 1 GB DDR3 Memory, and I was wondering if Ubuntu is compatible with Skype from new hardware installed.

The original webcam is still located on the computer, but I could not find it's icon through Ubuntu after Ubuntu was installed.

Therefore, I had to download a program called Cheese for Ubuntu to upload the new webcam info. Can someone please assist me with information concerning Skype to download to Ubuntu for Acer.

20% of my account remains open until Skype finishes downloading and has requested to convert this information to the computer.

How to solve this?

Comment: From where did you install Skype? You should install it from the Canonical Partner repository.

Answer (score 0):

This is not really an answer but it appears that you are having problems installing Skype on Ubuntu? or having problems with the web cam? Skype runs flawlessly on Ubuntu 14.04 (at least in mi case, with original or external cam), it will help to know what version of Ubuntu are you using?, what web cam do you have? etc.